# Deleted flag missing from activities returned from API when getting by contact id

Tags: api, activities

I would like to fetch activities by `contact_id` and only return non-deleted activities (or, failing that, return them all but filter them afterwards by `is_deleted`). But I find that passing is `is_deleted=0` does not make any difference and the `is_deleted` flag is not present on the returned data.

I guess this is a bug in the API? Is it known? I searched Jira but couldn't see it. If not I will file it and look at submitting a patch.

I can think of one workaround which is to fetch all the activity ids for the contact and then loop through them fetching each activity (since `in` does not seem to work with activity) by `activity_id` and `is_deleted`. But that could be a lot of api calls and means dealing with more async stuff if using JS. Anyone know of a cleaner workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the API should return the is_deleted! Having said so, if you want to make sure you have the latest version of the activity you could also use the `is_current_revision=1`?

*Editing to add a suggestion in the comments also by @ErikH, which was the solution I went for:*

> Not sure this is of any help but there is an extension for the
>   CaseActivity API: civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivity-api

Comment: If that means it hasn't been deleted then that is a good idea. I'll give it a try and get back to you, thanks

Comment: The problem happens only with Case activities. For example on the demo try searching for activities with contact id 202 and "is_current_revision". It will return a follow-up activity but if you look on 202's only case you will not see a follow-up activity, because I deleted it. The "is_current_revision" flag is also not returned

Comment: Also, "is_current_revision" and "is_deleted" can both be set to 1, so this would not help me to filter out deleted activities

Comment: Not sure this is of any help but there is an extension for the CaseActivity API: https://civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivity-api

Comment: Thanks @ErikH! That looks like it might do the trick, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on some of my civicrm installs, I didn't find any is_deleted=1 on my activity tables.

Do you have an example of one of your activities with that flag set? Do you have a better result with is_deleted=1 on your data?

and when I use the api explorer with is_deleted=0, I get the is_deleted attribute that is returned. What civicrm version do you have? Can you try to re-produce on the demo site?

Comment: The problem happens only with Case activities. For example on the demo try searching for activities with contact id 202 and not in trash. It will return a follow-up activity but if you look on 202's only case you will not see a follow-up activity, because I deleted it